# Menu, under search bar on nav-bar in Bootstrap...not compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a search bar with results that appear right under the bar, but I am faced with a number of problems while trying to implement this. I am new in web programming, which is why I prefer to use bootstrap because of its compatibility on different screen sizes. In this case, I don't know which method to use and I simply created "div" under the bar, but I am not sure if it is the correct way. Would be happy if you gave me suggestion.

Below I included the code with css that I used. 
I gave hard-coded value for the width as 174px, while I need something that automatically 
identifies the width of search bar and sets that value as maximum.
`ID="searchResults"` is the string that I get in real time using jQuery and Ajax.

Would be happy if you give me advice about the way how to implement this.

```
 <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text"
       autocomplete = off  id = "autocomplete_search">
      <div  id="searchResults" 
            style="position: absolute;
                width: 174px;
                background: white;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
                max-height: 200px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                margin-top: -3px;"> </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your attemp is ok. `.navbar-form navbar-left` needs to be `position: relative;`. 
If you do that, you can use this element to position and size the absolute container of `#searchResults`.

Your HTML is not valid, here is a more clean version:

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." type="text" autocomplete="off"  id="autocomplete_search" />
    <div id="searchResults">So much results...</div>
 </div>
```

Here is some CSS to put the html in shape:

```
.navbar-form
{
    position: relative;

    /* just a little demo */
    margin-left:200px;
}

.form-control
{
    width: 100%;
}

#searchResults
{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto; 
    background: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;

    border: 1px solid gray;

    /*This is relative to the navbar now*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20px;
}
```

And here is a little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/ZAyN9/

Comment: if you have a certain problem you can always create a new question. If you want information that is not too broad to explain, i'am in.

Comment: Okey,First, I dont know how to avoid a dot that appear in front of the searchresult. Second, what should I use to be able to move around searchResults by pressing arrow keys which will highlight searchResult and when enter pressed the page will be redirected (p.s searchResults are links to other page)

Comment: If it is too broad to explain, let me know and I will create another question

Comment: what do you mean by dot? do you put your search results in a `<ul>`? Then this will be the `list-style`. The other question about the searchable list, that is very complex. You could use jQuery+Ui for this. Have a look here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Yeap, I put it in the <ul> tags

Comment: That was a good idea to that. If you want to get rid of the style, do this: `<ul class="no-list-style"> ... </ul>` or any class name you like, with this css: `.no-list-style { list-style: none; }` you may also want to get rid of the default `margin` and `padding` those lists mostly have. But this is still far aways of a searchable, keyboard controlled widget- But a good start.